# Javascript - function with 2 parameters Okay, with 3 parameters returns value is not defined

Tags: javascript, function

I am doing a simple code on javascript. Basically, I have a button that onclick, calls a function and passes 3 parameters, as shown in the below line of code.

```js
$('<ul style="list-style:none;"><li><span style="font-weight: bold; color: white;">Message </span><span style="color: white;">' + 
item[i].message + '</span><br/><span style="font-weight: bold; color: white;">Date</span><span style="color: white;"> ' +
formatDate(date) + '</span><button style="float:right" id="' + item[i].id + '" onclick="postComment(' + item[i].id + ', ' +
sessionStorage.getItem("pageId") + ', ' + 
response.authResponse.accessToken + ')">Add Comment</button > <hr />').appendTo('#wellForPageFeed');
```

Now, all the values passed are not null as I print them before I click the function. In the function, for now, all I have is three console.log()s that print each element passed. The problem is that, on the last value passed (meaning the response.authResponse.accessToken) it gives the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: EAAEozLZBF2kgBACWvosqJN3ugl2vImHGIdPqsN9NQqXHw3EExaEQ7ePnUbLJxuu2Uu7ZCXYLg5qvil7fhnzc56zZCxBgmnMJwgPdcEsQJzZCWC2apzdJbFZAOrh4g4PO2ZAakk2l269HD0SxiiZB3TqHjNmRuS93Md9S22kPJ6xnIactGkjhfvqMhtmw5sqK60ZD is not defined
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

However, what baffles me is that, when I just pass the first two parameters, it works fine, however, passing the third parameter, which is basically a value, returns an error. What am I doing wrong please?

PS: This is the code for the function:

```
function postComment(postId, pageAccessToken, userAccessToken) {
    console.log("a "+postId)
    console.log("b " + pageAccessToken)
    console.log("c " + userAccessToken)
}
```

Comment: The access token is a string so you have to wrap it in quotes, otherwise it will be treated as identifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Helps to not have to mess with single and double quotes

Why a ul with one li? You were missing the `</li>` and `</ul>`

```js
const pageId = sessionStorage.getItem("pageId");
$(`<ul style="list-style:none;">
  <li>
    <span style="font-weight: bold; color: white;">Message </span>
    <span style="color: white;">${item[i].message}</span><br/>
    <span style="font-weight: bold; color: white;">Date</span>
    <span style="color: white;">${formatDate(date)}</span>
    <button style="float:right" id="${item[i].id}" data-token="${response.authResponse.accessToken}"
    onclick="postComment(this.id,pageId,this.dataset.token)">Add Comment</button > 
    <hr />
  </li>
</ul>`).appendTo('#wellForPageFeed');
```